# Discord py embed not working, but channel send directly before it is

Tags: python, discord.py, embed

I am working on a discord bot in python; i am trying to update my ctx.send to return an embed vs. a simple message.  My code is as follows.  Interestingly, the ctx.send works but then my bot doesn't send the embed directly below it and shows no errors.  Please note this is within a cog.

Also - the main.check_if_username_used(username) function and code WORKS.  The bot sends that first await.ctx.send message but then immediately fails the embed below it.  I also tried this with the title and description variables after defining username; same thing.

```
 @commands.command()
    async def register(self, ctx, name):
        """registers a user"""
        discord_id = ctx.author.id
        username = name

            
        # Check if discord_id already exists 
        # If yes, update username
        # If not, register the new user 
        if main.check_if_username_used(username) > 0:
            await ctx.send("That username already exists.  Please select another.")
            title = "***CAUTION***"
            description = "That username already exists.  Please select another."
            embed = discord.Embed(title = f'{title}', description = f'{description}', color = discord.Color.red)
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

I have tried many different methods of this including simply putting the text in the embed vs an F-String, i have tried creating the embed as a helper function but with that not working i moved to putting it directly into the command.

Comment: I am missing () after red.

Answer (score 1):

I missed () after discord.Color.red.

Should be discord.Color.red()

Answer (score 0):

Try turning on logging.

The Cog is loaded once Exception handlers are in place, so, any error you may have will be hidden. Turn the logging to DEBUG, and you will start to see the messages you need.

import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)